# How to save an image to a new directory?

Tags: python, jython

I am trying to save a file to a specific directory. The file ends up saving to the designated directory but when i go to open the file it tells me the file is empty.

```
import os
from os.path import join as pjoin
images = system.file.openFiles()
#os.chdir('O:\TestImages')
new_dir = 'O:\TestImages'
for image in images:
    system.file.readFileAsBytes(image)
    image_name = os.path.basename(image)
    saved_path = pjoin(new_dir,image_name)
    open(saved_path, "w")
    print(saved_path)
    system.db.runPrepUpdate("INSERT INTO ImageManagement (ImageName) VALUES (?)", [image_name])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
import os
from os.path import join as pjoin
images = system.file.openFiles()
#os.chdir('O:\TestImages')
new_dir = 'O:\TestImages'
for image in images:
    image_data = system.file.readFileAsBytes(image)
    image_name = os.path.basename(image)
    saved_path = pjoin(new_dir,image_name)
    with open(saved_path, "wb") as image_file:
        image_file.write(image_data)
    print(saved_path)
    system.db.runPrepUpdate("INSERT INTO ImageManagement (ImageName) VALUES (?)", [image_name])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).